# How to select all checkboxes in just one particular column in GridView?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a GridView in which there are two columns of checkboxes i want to add two seperate "check all" text boxes at the top, "check all" above column A should check all the checkboxes in that column only. "check all" above column B should check all the columns in column B only.  Also i am not able to apply groupvalidation. For every row only one of the two columns should get selected. I tried finding solution but when i click on check all at the top it checks all the checkboxes present in the gridview and also there is no group validation. Here is my Code..

HEAD:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Check_Click(objRef) {
        //Get the Row based on checkbox
        var row = objRef.parentNode.parentNode;
        if (objRef.checked) {
            //If checked change color to Aqua
            row.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
        }
        else {
            //If not checked change back to original color
            if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
                //Alternating Row Color
                row.style.backgroundColor = "#C2D69B";
            }
            else {
                row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
        }

        //Get the reference of GridView
        var GridView = row.parentNode;

        //Get all input elements in Gridview
        var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
            //The First element is the Header Checkbox
            var headerCheckBox = inputList[0];

            //Based on all or none checkboxes
            //are checked check/uncheck Header Checkbox
            var checked = true;
            if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i] != headerCheckBox) {
                if (!inputList[i].checked) {
                    checked = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        headerCheckBox.checked = checked;

    }
</script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function checkAll(objRef) {
        var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
            //Get the Cell To find out ColumnIndex
            var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;
            if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && objRef != inputList[i]) {
                if (objRef.checked) {
                    //If the header checkbox is checked
                    //check all checkboxes
                    //and highlight all rows
                    row.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
                    inputList[i].checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    //If the header checkbox is checked
                    //uncheck all checkboxes
                    //and change rowcolor back to original 
                    if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
                        //Alternating Row Color
                        row.style.backgroundColor = "#C2D69B";
                    }
                    else {
                        row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    }
                    inputList[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

BODY:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="RollNo" HeaderText="RollNo" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                                        TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderTemplate>                                   
                                    &nbsp;
           </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2"
                                        runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2">
                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Time" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Absent">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Absent" />
                                    &nbsp;
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Present">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Present" 
                                        onclick = "Check_Click(this)" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found solution to my problem. Although there is still one glitch.

Head:

```
  <div runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SelectAll(id) {
            //get reference of GridView control
            var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
            //variable to contain the cell of the grid
            var cell;

            if (grid.rows.length > 0) {
                //loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
                for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
                    //get the reference of first column
                    cell = grid.rows[i].cells[4];

                    //loop according to the number of childNodes in the cell
                    for (j = 0; j < cell.childNodes.length; j++) {
                        //if childNode type is CheckBox                 
                        if (cell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox") {
                            //assign the status of the Select All checkbox to the cell checkbox within the grid
                            cell.childNodes[j].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        function SelectAll1(id) {
            //get reference of GridView control
            var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
            //variable to contain the cell of the grid
            var cell;

            if (grid.rows.length > 0) {
                //loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
                for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
                    //get the reference of first column
                    cell = grid.rows[i].cells[3];

                    //loop according to the number of childNodes in the cell
                    for (j = 0; j < cell.childNodes.length; j++) {
                        //if childNode type is CheckBox                 
                        if (cell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox") {
                            //assign the status of the Select All checkbox to the cell checkbox within the grid
                            cell.childNodes[j].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

 <script type = "text/javascript">
     function CheckBoxCheck(rb) {
         var gv = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID%>");
         var row = rb.parentNode.parentNode;
         var rbs = row.getElementsByTagName("input");
         for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
             if (rbs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                 if (rbs[i].checked && rbs[i] != rb) {
                     rbs[i].checked = false;
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
     }   
</script>



        </div>
```

Body:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="RollNo" HeaderText="RollNo" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                                        TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderTemplate>                                   
                                    &nbsp;
           </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2"
                                        runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2">
                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Time" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Present">
                                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll1" runat="server" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this)" />
                                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll1" runat="server" Text="All Absent" 
                                        onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this)" AutoPostBack="True" ValidationGroup="a" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll1" runat="server" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this)" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this)"/>
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll" runat="server" Text="All Present" 
                            onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this)" AutoPostBack="True" ValidationGroup="a" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            //Find the checkbox control in header and add an attribute
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectAll('" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll")).ClientID + "')");
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll1")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectAll1('" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll1")).ClientID + "')");
        }
    }
```

The glitch is that user can still select both the "check all" and therefore both the columns get selected at the same time. Athough only one can be selected when not using select all check box.